# ElasticSearch equivalent query for SQL group by multiple columns

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a few million documents with name and version (both of type keyword) as properties in each. What is the equivalent Elastic query for group by name, version?

I have tried the following query:

```
{
"size":0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "time": {
                    "gte": "2017-01-28",
                    "lte": "2017-02-28"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "group_by_name": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "name"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "group_by_version": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "version"
                }   
            }
        }   
    }       
}
```

}

However the results are not same as doing Group by name, version.
The results are grouped by name and within each group, they are grouped by version.
How do I modify the above query to group by name, version tuple and return results in descending order?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Update:
What i get is:

```
{
  "took": 1424,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 115,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_name": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 2,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 115,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "product1",
          "doc_count": 50,
          "group_by_version": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 50,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "1.0",
                "doc_count": 40
              },
              {
                "key": "2.0",
                "doc_count": 10
              },
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "product3",
          "doc_count": 35,
          "group_by_version": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 4,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 35,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "8.0",
                "doc_count": 20
              },
              {
                "key": "9.0",
                "doc_count": 15
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "product2",
          "doc_count": 30,
          "group_by_version": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 30,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "4.0",
                "doc_count": 25
              },
              {
                "key": "5.0",
                "doc_count": 5
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What i want is:

```
name, version   count
product1 1.0    40
product2 4.0    25
product3 8.0    20
product3 9.0    15
product1 2.0    10
product2 5.0     5
```

Comment: Can you show what you get and what you would like to get instead?

Comment: I don't think it is supported by ES. You can have a merged field while indexing or you can handle it in your code.

Comment: i have updated with actual vs expected. Thank you for your time

Comment: Krrish - currently i handle this logic in code. But the dataset is too large that i am losing out the benefit of sub-second response time. Group by x,y feature is available in SQL